# Correction required when autocorrelation stems from the explanatory variable?

Tags: regression, autocorrelation

I am a bit ignorant of when to correct for autocorrelation. Is it important to correct for this when *persistence* is only an issue in the explanatory variable?

For example, I am looking at the relationship between a large scale atmospheric process (which probably has some degree of autocorrelation) and another index of a primary production (where the index is largely *reset* over the winter, but its summer amplitude may be affected by the atmospheric conditions). Thus, there is possibly a degree of autocorrelation in the response index as well, but only because of the relationship to the explanatory variable, and not true persistence at the annual scale due to the intermediate resets.

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: See [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9745) and [a similar one](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/38802) on Quantitative Finance SE.